# setting up ACL permissions from shell or code? CAKEPHP

Tags: php, cakephp, acl, cakephp-2.3

I'm new to cake and I'm currently trying to implement the [Simple Acl Controlled Application Tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/part-two.html) from CakePHP.

I have reached the [setting permissions part](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/part-two.html#setting-up-permissions), but I'm not sure how I am meant to implement the permissions, I have three groups (Admin, Responder and Volunteer).

I noticed on [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BgcYZXwvO-k)'s and other tutorials that people are using a controller to implement the Access Control Lists, but I think that is only meant to be for cake 1.3.

If you could help me know how I am supposed to implement the ACL (shell or controller) and show me some example's then that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [*ACL shell*](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/acl-shell.html) would allow you to handle everything ACL related, although it requires some familiarization with ACL in general before you get the hang of it. Personally, I prefer to embed my ACL administration inside my applications by using an ACL plugin. That way everything can be handled web-based from within the app itself by people in the Administrators ARO (or more if you'd like).

I have been using the [*Alaxos ACL Plugin*](http://www.alaxos.ch/blaxos/pages/view/plugin_acl_2.0) in some of my projects and it works like a charm. All the documentation on how to set it up is on the site as well.

Comment: have i reached far enough in the tutorial to be able to implement this plug in?

Comment: If you have setup your `aros`, `acos` and `aros_acos` tables in your database (or ran the `initdb` command from ACL shell) and added at least 1 group/role, then yes.

Comment: i have installed the plug in following the instructions but i now have the following error, `The Role model is not configured to act as an ACL requester`

Comment: That means that you have not completed [this step](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html#acts-as-a-requester) of the tutorial (or misconfigured the `acl.aro.role.model` Plugin setting to point to another Model than your Group/Role model).

Comment: i made it point to the group model, but now i have this error `DbAcl::check() - Failed ARO/ACO node lookup in permissions check.  Node references:
Aro: Array`

Comment: Make sure you added your own User id to the `acl.role.access_plugin_user_ids` setting. If you need any additional help, find me in the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24337/cakephp).

Answer (score 0):

use

```
bin/cake acl_extras aco_sync
```

and then use

```
bin/cake acl grant Groups.3 controllers/Posts/index
```

here 3 is the group id